# Android TextView horizontal scroll delay

Tags: android, scroll, textview, delay

I am trying to implement a ListView which contains a TextView that scrolls automatically when the text gets too long. So far so good but my problem is that the scrolling starts immediatelly after the item is shown and thus the user has no chance to read the first few letters. I was wondering if there is any kind of a delay for that scrolling to start?

Here's my code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_track"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question.

I solved this by using a handler that runs on the UI thread:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(() -> textView.setSelected(true), 1000);
```

Handler's postDelayed() lets you fire a runnable after a certain amount of time elapses. In my example the text view will sit for 1 second (1000 milliseconds) and then the scrolling animation starts when the handler executes.